# allow machine to access localhost website

Tags: firewall, ip, windows-server-2012

I've got some IP rules on an Azure VM, the first blocks all traffic, the second allows my laptop to access the website. Both work fine, however when I try to access a website hosted on the VM locally the traffic gets blocked.

I tried setting up an additional rule with the source IP as 'My IP Address' but that didn't seem to work, I don't have a static IP address on this.

Any ideas on how I can maintain a block on all external traffic, allow just my laptop (which does have a static IP address) but continue to allow browsing the website from the VM?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to add "localhost" aka 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yep, when I tried to save it, I got a message stating, that 'The loopback address (127.0.0.1) is not a valid source or destination address.'

Comment: Not entirely sure on this, but: You might want to try setting up an IPSec connection on both, your server and computer. Edit your block rule to only block if there is no secure connection. Then you can create a rule that allows traffic, if there is a secure connection.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved the issue.

For the IP security rule implementing the block action, the connection tile was 'All Connections'.

These were the steps I followed to resolve the issue

1. Open up MMC,
2. 'File' > 'Add/remove Snap-in'
3. Select 'IP Security Policies'
4. Select the relevant policy and click Edit,
5. Select the connection type tab,
6. change the connection type from 'All Network' connections to 'Remote Access'

Then presto I could access localhost again